# Как менять состояние галки в CheckListBox по нажатию на текст?

Tags: delphi, checkbox

У обычно CheckBox регулирование флажком возможно при нажатии на текст. Как этого же добиться у CheckListBox?

Answer (score 1):

выставить флаг при клике  в текст можно вручную обработав событие клика в листбокс. Например, так:

```
procedure TForm1.CheckListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var p : TPoint;
    idx : integer;
begin
    p := CheckListBox1.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
    idx := CheckListBox1.ItemAtPos( p, true);

    if idx >= 0 then begin
        CheckListBox1.Checked[idx] := not CheckListBox1.Checked[idx];
        if(assigned(CheckListBox1.OnClickCheck)) then begin
            CheckListBox1.OnClickCheck(sender);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, я сделал подобное с ItemIndex , но так нажатие на квадрат не работает